# Get the Content-Type of an Outlook MailItem

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook VSTO in C#, targeting Outlook 2010. I need to get the MIME Content-Type of a message (think `text/plain` or its more exotic alternatives). The only place I can find this is in the message headers, which is a long string that I'd prefer not to need to read and parse manually.

MSDN documents the [PidNameContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842347.aspx) property ([alternate link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200439(v=exchg.80).aspx)), but I can't get it to work. Anything like that always fails (not found).

```
String ct = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
    "urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type"); // Not found
String ct2 = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/content-type"); // Not found
```

Weirdly, this even fails for a [documented example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147567.aspx) that is similar:

```
String ct2 = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/content-class"); // Not found
```

On the other hand, some of the "more common" headers, like `urn:schemas:mailheader:subject`, work fine.

Am I just using the `PropertyAccessor` wrong? Does Outlook not actually parse out the Content-Type header and I simply need to do it manually? Is there some other way to get this header's contents?

Comment: Maybe you can use proptag's, e.g. GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms526356(v=exchg.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN for a list of valid identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the entire header first and then searching through that string to get what you need?

```
Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E" 
Outlook.PropertyAccessor olPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor;
String Header = olPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS);
```

Source: [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1074498/Outlook-add-in-in-Csharp-get-message-header)

Comment: Entirely possible, but falls under the `"Does Outlook not actually parse out the Content-Type header and I simply need to do it manually?"` part of the question. Given how much stuff Outlook parses out automatically, the fact that there's a named property that is exactly the thing I want, and the fact that one of the reasons I'm writing this add-in is because the ones it's intended to replace have bad performance, I was really hoping for a better solution.